# How can I access files in another program's Application Data in a Windows 8 app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am writing a Windows 8 App that requires access to files in another program's application data.  I have read over [Window's file permssion guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx) and did not see a way to do it.  Is this even possible?  If so, how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer.  I can tell the user to select their user folder in the folder picker. Then once I get that permission, I can programmatiically navigate to the required files in the application data folder.

Answer (score 5):

Not possible using winrt API. It is like IsolatedStorage per process.

[File access and permissions in Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh967755.aspx)

But using Hack it is possible to bypass sandbox environment.

[How to bypass WinRT / Metro sandbox using simple trick.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1541924)[Sample + Guide](http://suchan.cz/wp7/OutOfSandboxSample.7z)

But such app will not pass windows 8 compatibility test while submitting to App Store.

Comment: That is the article I linked to in my post.  I believe that this may be possible using a folder picker, or something of the like.  Could that work?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but my intent is to distribute this through the Windows Store, so that is not a favorable option.

Comment: YOu can use the folder picker -- but that means the user needs to explicitly select the file all the time; you can't just go auto discover it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible from windows store app, they are sandboxed and needs to declare capabilities such as access to internet, camera and similar, and you surley can't declare that you want to read other app data.

Comment: Is it possible using a folder picker, or something like that?

Comment: Not possible through file/folder picker. But i remember it is possible using native code bypassing winrt but then such app will not pass windows 8 compatibility test while submitting to App Store

Comment: @Garrett It **is** possible [using a filepicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465174.aspx)

Comment: @GameScripting How would I do that? I have started trying to use it, but currently `AppData` does not show up unless I remove the hidden attribute.

Comment: @Garrett It's up to you to find out ;) The link I provided can help you to find out. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible if you don't know how to use .net for Windows 8 stor.

With this you get save location:

```
using Windows.Storage;
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

And with this you can retrieve data by app URI:

```
using Windows.Storage;
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync("ms-appdata:///local/file.txt");
```

Source: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh967755.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#locations_all_apps_can_access

Comment: This will only give me access to my app's app data, but I am trying to access the app data of another program

Comment: Sorry for spamming then :(

Answer (score 0):

This answer depends on the other application and the type of files you're trying to access, but perhaps you can implement support for the Share contract and tell Windows what kinds of files you're willing to accept.  The user then can use the other application and Share with your application if they choose.  I'm not sure how viable this will be for your needs however as you don't provide much detail as to what data you're trying to get at.